# How can I change the default color variables using scss in Ionic?

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, sass

I have been working with Ionic for some time now but am not sure how to use scss along with it. While building a new Ionic project I have a scss folder with a scss file in it. I have tried everything possible but my changes are not affecting the CSS of my page. Can anyone tell me exactly what I need to do to work with scss? All we are trying to do is change the default color variables provided by Ionic.

I have completed the necessary setup required as described [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/sass.html).

**Here is my `ionic.app.scss` file inside scss folder:**

```
/*
To customize the look and feel of Ionic, you can override the variables
in ionic's _variables.scss file.

For example, you might change some of the default colors:

$light:                           #fff !default;
$stable:                          #f8f8f8 !default;
$positive:                        #387ef5 !default;
$calm:                            #11c1f3 !default;
$balanced:                        #33cd5f !default;
$energized:                       #ffc900 !default;
$assertive:                       #ef473a !default;
$royal:                           #886aea !default;
$dark:                            #444 !default;
*/

// The path for our ionicons font files, relative to the built CSS in www/css
$ionicons-font-path: "../lib/ionic/fonts" !default;

// Include all of Ionic
@import "www/lib/ionic/scss/ionic";
```

**Here is my _variables.scss file inside `lib/ionic/scss` folder:**

```
// Colors
// -------------------------------

$light:                           #fff !default;
$stable:                          #f8f8f8 !default;
$positive:                        #387ef5 !default;
$calm:                            #11c1f3 !default;
$balanced:                        #33cd5f !default;
$energized:                       #ffc900 !default;
$assertive:                       #ef473a !default;
$royal:                           #886aea !default;
$dark:                            #444 !default;


// Base
// -------------------------------

$font-family-sans-serif:           '-apple-system', "Helvetica Neue", "Roboto", "Segoe UI", sans-serif !default;

$font-family-light-sans-serif:    '-apple-system', "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Roboto-Light", "Segoe UI-Light", sans-serif-light !default;
```

Changes made in the `_variables.scss` are not shown in my app and I don't understand why.

Here is my console after running gulp in it.

```
abc-Mac-mini:FileFolder xyz$ gulp
[10:34:49] Using gulpfile /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/FileFolder/gulpfile.js
[10:34:49] Starting 'sass'...
[10:34:50] Finished 'sass' after 731 ms
[10:34:50] Starting 'default'...
[10:34:50] Finished 'default' after 15 μs
abc-Mac-mini:FileFolder xyz$
```

Comment: Can you write `gulp` in a command line interface and share what it returns? It may be that you are missing the necessary dependencies to compile the scss.

Comment: Hi Dexter, I have added console return after running gulp in my question. Please check.

Comment: Do you have problems with all CSS properties or only with the `_variables.scss` file?

Comment: Right now I am not trying to use _variables.scss. My main concern at the moment is to make change to the default css behavior like changing color of 'positive' to red or green and 'assertive' to black or grey etc. For this we just need to change the color in scss/ionic.app.scss. I created a example, it's working fine in it but not in my main application. Am not sure what am I doing wrong. Please let me know if you want me to share anything with you.

Answer (score 0):

you will have the following file in your ionic project.

```
www/css/ionic.app.css
```

copy all css from this file and paste it into your `scss` file.

now start making changes in scss file

Comment: Can you brief it please. I will copy all code from www/css/ionic.app.css and paste to scss/ionic.app.css. Suppose now if I want to change the color of assertive to green. what all changes I need to do?

Comment: when you done with copying, now you just need to change in your .scss file.. it will reflect the changes

Comment: I have followed this. what you're saying is similar to the video below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_frPHsE2PZk

But this is not working at all. My scss file is making no effect.

Comment: I believe I am missing something.

This is the path to the 2 files needed

// The path for our ionicons font files, relative to the built CSS in www/css
$ionicons-font-path: "../lib/ionic/fonts" !default;

// Include all of Ionic
@import "www/lib/ionic/scss/ionic";

Comment: The `ionic.app.css` contains all the CSS that has been compiled, including CSS from the Ionic library, you are duplicating a lot of CSS by doing this. I would highly recommend to not take this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to override the default colors provided by Ionic, like `$positive` and `$assertive`. The recommended way to do this is to override the existing variables defined by Ionic and not by changing variables inside the Ionic source files.

When you start an Ionic project, you get the following comments on top in the `ionic.app.scss` file:

```
/*
  To customize the look and feel of Ionic, you can override the variables
  in ionic's _variables.scss file.

  For example, you might change some of the default colors:

  $light:                           #fff !default;
  $stable:                          #f8f8f8 !default;
  $positive:                        #387ef5 !default;
  $calm:                            #11c1f3 !default;
  $balanced:                        #33cd5f !default;
  $energized:                       #ffc900 !default;
  $assertive:                       #ef473a !default;
  $royal:                           #886aea !default;
  $dark:                            #444 !default;
*/
```

So all you have to do is uncomment the variables you want to change and it should be reflected in your app. Make sure that these variables are declared before Ionic is imported, because otherwise the Ionic color variables will override your custom variables.

An example:

```
$positive: #FF0000 !default;

// The path for our ionicons font files, relative to the built CSS in www/css
$ionicons-font-path: "../lib/ionic/fonts" !default;

// Include all of Ionic
@import "www/lib/ionic/scss/ionic";
```

This will turn all elements using the `$positive` color to red. Also make sure that you check the console to see whether there are compilations errors, because if there is an error in the CSS file, gulp will not compile. Furthermore, don't forget that the scss needs to be compiled every time you make a change. This is done automatically when you use `ionic serve` to test or if you run `gulp watch`.